# Converting multiple key-value pairs into JSON format: how to use sed within a for loop of awk

Tags: json, bash, awk, sed

I have a data file that's pipe delimited with 8 columns, and the last column is an unpredictable # of key-value pairs that are associated with one another with the = sign and each key-value pair is separated by a space. The unfortunate thing is, the values in each key-value pair can also contain a space in them.

Here's an example of one record in the input data file:

```
Val1|Val2|Val3|Val4|Val5|Val6|Val7| key1=70 key2=11\=12 key3=Some other value key4=Another value
```

Here's the final output I need to get it to (which shows all key-value pairs in the 8th column in JSON format):

```
Val1|Val2|Val3|Val4|Val5|Val6|Val7|{"key1":"70", "key2":"11\=12", "key3":"Some other value", "key4":"Another value"}
```

Here's an example of where I can currently get the data to look like (so we can consider working with the data in this format; going forward, lets assume this string is contained in a variable called mydata):

```
Val1|Val2|Val3|Val4|Val5|Val6|Val7|{"key1":"70 key2":"11\=12 key3":"Some other value key4":"Another value"}
```

But I'm missing is the ", " that will separate the end of the previous value with the next key name.

At this point, I have a need to do a S&R within the loop of an awk command so that for each iteration, it separates the previous value (in the key-value pair) from the next key name with double quotes, comma, space and double quotes (", ")

I have the final awk command written out, but it's absent of the S&R that I need to happen for each iteration in the awk's for loop:

```
echo $mydata | awk -F '\":\"' '{ str1 = $1; for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) str1 = str1 "\":\"" $i; print str1 }'
```

So, how do I incorporate this S&R logic into the for loop of the awk?

FYI, here's the code I used to get ias far as I could:

```
test="Val1|Val2|Val3|Val4|Val5|Val6|Val7| key1=70 key2=11\=12 key3=Some other value key4=Another value";

echo $test | awk -F '|' '{print $1 "|" $2 "\x1c" $3 "|" $4 "|" $5 "|" $6 "|" $7 "|" "{\"" $8 "\"}" }' \
| sed -e 's/{\" /{\"/g' -e 's/\\=/\x07/g' -e 's/[[:space:]]*=/\":\"/g' -e 's/\x07/\\=/g'
```

Comment: Update the post with that don't use a comment.

Comment: What code do you have currently that takes the input and creates your current output? Show us whatever it is.

Comment: Updating with both of those pieces should be allowed I think. I can't see why it wouldn't be. Try again. If you still can't do it I can try to pull them out of your comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do the whole thing with sed, if your data is reasonably regular, i.e. nothing that looks like `" key="` in any of the `val`s, keys consist only of word characters:

```
sed 's/| \(\w\w*\)=/|{"\1"="/;
     s/$/"}/;
     s/ \(\w\w*\)=/" "\1"="/g'
```

The "key" is to note that the original "keys" are always `<space><word>=`

Tested:

```
$ sed 's/| \(\w\w*\)=/|{"\1"="/;s/$/"}/;s/ \(\w\w*\)=/" "\1"="/g'
Val1|Val2|Val3|Val4|Val5|Val6|Val7| key1=70 key2=11\=12 key3=Some other value key4=Another value
Val1|Val2|Val3|Val4|Val5|Val6|Val7|{"key1"="70" "key2"="11\=12" "key3"="Some other value" "key4"="Another value"}
```

Comment: That, Jeff Y, was OUTSTANDING!  Very impressed with this solution; more elegant than the option I was attempting to entertain.

One minor update I had to make to your solution, was to add in a comma so that " " looks like ", "


here's your answer:


sed 's/| \(\w\w*\)=/|{"\1"="/; s/$/"}/; s/ \(\w\w*\)=/" "\1"="/g'


here's what I had to change:


sed 's/| \(\w\w*\)=/|{"\1"="/; s/$/"}/; s/ \(\w\w*\)=/", "\1"="/g'


You just saved me a ton of frustration and wasted hours.  THANKS!

Comment: You're welcome. Always keep it as simple as the data allows, is my motto.